# How do I make my web app's main page look different depending on whether the user signed in

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a full stack application using reactjs and spring boot. My main page has a login button, which when you click it takes you to the login page. (I'm using React Router.) Ideally, i would like that when someone logs in successfully, they are rerouted back to the main page- which now has additional features. (like saying "Hi (username)") I'm not sure how I would do this, please help!

Comment: Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: What's the specific issue? You can conditionally render components, use a router to go to a completely different component, etc.

Comment: I want it to be the same component, just have different features depending on whether the user is signed in- I think it's silly to make two different main pages and render one if he's signed in and another if he isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

```
...

state = { isSignedIn: false }

render() {
    <div>
         {this.state.isSignedIn ? <div>Stuff to show if signed in</div> : <div>Stuff to show if not signed in</div>}
    </div>
}
...
```

In your login handler call `setState` on `isSignedIn` to toggle it to true.

Comment: Right but the isSignedIn state is being set in a different component- how do I pass it back to the main page?

Comment: Move the SignedIn state and the handler up to the parent, then pass it down as a prop to the child.

Comment: @user9832813 take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up

Comment: and then i set it like this: this.props.isLoggedIn:true? (or whatever)

Comment: You could just do `this.props.isLoggedIn ? ...`. You don't have to explicitly write `true`.